# Pharo 5.0 - Cannot play sounds - soundStart: snd_add_pcm_handler: Function not implemented

Tags: pharo

The platform is Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm executing `FMSound organ1 play.`

and receiving `soundStart: snd_add_pcm_handler: Function not implemented`

in the terminal window.

I've tried starting Pharo 5.0 using:
`pasuspender -- ./pharo ../shared/Pharo5.0.image` 
but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

SoundPlugin appears to be loaded in the system reporter.

SoundPlugin VMMaker.oscog-EstebanLorenzano.829 (i)

But:
http://bugs.squeak.org/view.php?id=7328
http://forum.world.st/VM-Crash-on-Linux-td3322149.html

Looks like this isn't fixed yet.

Latest VM+Pharo6.0 also exhibit the problem.

Comment: Issue opened: https://pharo.fogbugz.com/f/cases/19503/PharoSound-not-working-on-Ubuntu-14-and-16